# Projection before Join

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is it possible using cypher to force projection before join?

In the following example, assuming that movie "m" stared 255 actors, I would expect around 255 db hits. The plan, however, decides to do NodeHashJoin before Projection, resulting in more than 2 * 255<sup>2</sup> db hits.

```
MATCH (actorA)-->(m:Movie {name:"m"})<--(actorB)
USING JOIN ON m
WITH  actorA.id AS aid, actorB.id AS bid
WHERE aid < bid
RETURN aid, bid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want pairs of actors from a cross product of all actors in the movie, then use an inequality on the id to prevent matching on the same pairs of actors. There are a couple ways we can improve this one.

With your current plan, you're expanding to the actors of the movie twice, once for actorA and another for actorB. We can change this to only expand to actors once, get these into a collection (using pattern comprehension), and get the cross product you need by unwinding the collection twice, then performing the filtering.

In addition, rather than relying on the filtering by a property id, which requires property access, we can do that filtering based on the neo4j internal id.

Give this one a try:

```
WITH [(actor)-->(:Movie {name:"m"}) | actor] as actors
UNWIND actors as actorA
UNWIND actors as actorB
WITH actorA, actorB
WHERE id(actorA) < id(actorB)
RETURN actorA.id AS aid, actorB.id AS bid
```

And if you want to force the projection of the ids before your UNWINDs, you can do this at the very start, and just use the id properties instead of the nodes for the rest:

```
WITH [(actor)-->(:Movie {name:"m"}) | actor.id] as actors
UNWIND actors as aid
UNWIND actors as bid
WITH aid, bid
WHERE aid < bid
RETURN aid, bid
```